# Is there a way to stop to_dict() from updating strings to datetime?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to develop a general solution to upload data from a dataframe to a MySQL table.  The MySQL insert statement requires a ON DUPLCIATE KEY UPDATE so I can't just use to_sql().  I have it working fairly well, except in some cases to_dict() is converting date strings ('YYYY-MM-DD') to datetimes which can't be used in the query.  Does anyone know if we can stop to_dict from converting the type?

Comment: May I ask why the datetimes in the database are being stored as strings (`VARCHAR`?) rather than as `DATETIME`?  If stored as `DATETIME` the conversion shouldn’t be an issue.  Or have I misunderstood ...

Comment: Or ... the `to_sql()` function can still be used if you (I know ...) iterate the DataFrame; (`.iterrows()`), then the `ON DUPLICATE` will still function. (We run a similar method on a project.)

Answer (score 0):

After you import your df into python

```
df['column'].astype(str)
```

See if this works, I don't have enough info to test this myself. Regardless the pandas.DataFrame.astype function will probably be useful. [Link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html#pandas.DataFrame.astype)

Edit: Tested with an example dictionary, definitely works

Comment: Thanks - I'm trying to develop a general solution for any dataframe I pass.  So the function can't know the column name.  Also, the dataframe column is a string before I convert the dataframe to dict